# Changing list/menu in php to behave like a text field but still populating data from mysql database

Tags: php

Below is my code, and it's working fine. However, how can I change from selection  to say TEXT Field so as one can type, while the prioritized are listed down as in combo box?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databasse");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

else {
    echo "Select Region: ";
    echo "<select name='RegName' id='RegName'>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM rtable";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    //echo "<option value='userid'>All</option>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='RegName'>".$row['RegName']." </option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, is there any other way to describe it? By the way, I'm not so sure your code will work the way you expect it to. All your options will end up having the same value. Were you thinking of `'<option value="' . $row['RegName'] . '">' . $row['RegName'] . " </option>";`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a textfield?

Comment: Jason and Sam. my interest is to have like <form action="form1.php" method="post">
 <input name="select" id="select" list="browsers">
 <datalist id="browsers">
   <option value="Kenya">  <option value="USA">  <option value="Sweden">   <option value="Colombia"> 
 </datalist> but rather than putting options, I want to get them from my mysql database field named RegName